# How to autowire Common Controller Dependencies in Symfony using an Abstract class

Tags: php, symfony, autowired, symfony4

I have created an abstract BaseController class that extends AbstractController.
This is so that all the Common Dependencies don't have to be injected in each Controller class that I have (e.g. EntityManager and RequestStack).

However, I have some Controller classes where I would like to inject additional services in the constructor, but this is causing problems.

```
// src/Controller/BaseController.php
namespace App\Controller;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

abstract class BaseController extends AbstractController
{
    protected $em;
    protected $request;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, RequestStack $request)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->request = $request->getCurrentRequest();
    }
}
```

I can then just extend my Controller classes and call for example $this->em in any of the methods.

However, let's say that I wanted to do the following:

```
// src/Controller/DashboardController.php
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface;

class DashboardController extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct(TranslatorInterface $translator)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->translator = $translator;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        // use $this->translator()
    }
}
```

This would cause an error as the constructor of the BaseController is expecting two arguments to be passed.
I've tried adding the following to my services.yaml but to no avail:

```
App\Controller\BaseController:
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager', '@request_stack']
```

What would be the best way to autowire these arguments, and would this be a good practice?

Comment: Won't claim it is the best but one approach is to make a TranslatorTrait and use the required annotation to inject the translator service.  Here is an [example](https://github.com/cerad/traits/blob/master/src/Core/RouterTrait.php).  Take a look at the DefaultController to see it in action.

Comment: You still have pass in you parent class dependencies into `parent::__construct(/* Here */);`, I don't think there is another way.